# How can I assign a value to a property of a static object inside a static class?

Tags: c#

I have this assignment:

```
Counts.btnCountViewsAvg.BtnCount = 123;
```

Here are the classes that I use:

```
public static class Counts
{
    public static BtnCountViews btnCountViewsAvg;
}

public class BtnCountViews // this class used in many places
{
    public int BtnCount { get; set; }
    public int Views { get; set; }
}
```

What I would like to do is to assign 123 to BtnCount but it says cannot assign to a null. When I check the btnCountViewsAvg is null. I used static as I only want to have one Counts class in the application.

Can someone give me some advice on how I can assign a value to Counts.btnCountViewsAvg.BtnCount

Comment: Becase `BtnCountViews` isn't `static`, perhaps?

Comment: "but it says cannot assign to a null" - please provide the *exact* error message.

Comment: If I make btnCountViews static can I then use that in different parts of my application when for example getting data with LINQ?

Comment: Jon,  it can't assign as btnCountViewsAvg as is null when I check.

Comment: @Alan2: Right, that's not the same as "it says cannot assign to a null". If you'd provided a [mcve] you'd have received a NullReferenceException. So you need to make `btnCountViewsAvg` non-null, by assigning a value to it, creating an instance of `BtnCountViews`. (As an aside, I'd strongly recommend avoiding public fields and avoiding this sort of use of static anyway, but that's a different matter. I'd also avoid the abbreviation of "btn" everywhere.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is your `Counts.btnCountViewsAvg` that is null. You need to instantiate that before being able to set the `BtnCount` property.

To instantiate the value you need to do the following:

```
Counts.btnCountViewsAvg = new BtwCountViews();
```

Furthermore you could instantiate using the object initialiser it like so:

```
Counts.btnCountViewsAvg = new BtwCountViews { BtnCount = 123 };
```

In order to ensure that `btnCountViewsAvg` is only created once you could do the following:

```
public static class Counts
{
    public readonly static BtnCountViews btnCountViewsAvg = new BtnCountViews();
}
```

Or to follow on from Jon Skeets suggestion with using a property rather than a public field this would be a better approach:

```
public static class Counts
{
    public static ButtonCountViews ButtonCountViewsAvg { get; } = new ButtonCountViews();
}
```

Note I renamed your class to remove the abbreviation.

Comment: As the btnCountViewsAvg is in a static class then am I right to assume I can only do this once.  In which case where would it be created?

Comment: No static does not mean it can only be created once, if you want to create it only once then you need to look at the readonly keyword.

Comment: @Alan2 furthermore if you want a single instance created then you could also look up the Singleton pattern

Comment: I tried making btnCountViewsAvg static but then get an error message when using it like this <btnCountViewsAvg> in other parts of the code.

Answer (score 1):

You have two options:

- Create new object only once

  ```
  public static class Counts
  {
      public static BtnCountViews btnCountViewsAvg = new BtnCountViews();
  }
  ```
- Or create it every time you need it:

  ```
  Counts.btnCountViewsAvg = new BtnCountViews() 
  { 
      BtnCount = 123
  };
  ```

Comment: You could add a readonly keyword to the first example to guarantee it is only created once.

Comment: @Bijington - can you give me an example of what you mean?  Thanks

Comment: @Bijington I think then it is better convert it to get only property: `public static BtnCountViews BtnCountViewsAvg { get; } = new BtnCountViews();`

Comment: @YuriyN. I would agree, it seems there is a fair amount that needs to be pointed out with the implementation so I was just trying to take it 1 step at a time :).

Answer (score 1):

You, probably, want something like this: create an instance of `BtnCountViews` with `BtnCount = 123` and assign it to static field:

```
public static class Counts
{
    // we create a instance: new btnCountViewsAvg() 
    // then we set up a property of this instance: { BtnCount = 123, }
    public static BtnCountViews btnCountViewsAvg = new btnCountViewsAvg() {
      BtnCount = 123,
    };
}
```